# Labeling first and last data point in matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have plotted a set of data points in a 3D figure and I would like to label the first and last data point with a different color and label them by a legend. How do I do that?

The code I have used is

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3])
z = np.array([0,1,2,3])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot(x,y,z,'o-',markersize=5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redraw the first and last point on the plot and label them as you give them color.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3])
z = np.array([0,1,2,3])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot(x[:1], y[:1], z[:1], 'o-',c='green', label="first", zorder=2)
ax.plot(x[-1:], y[-1:], z[-1:], 'o-',c='coral', label="last", zorder=2)
ax.plot(x,y,z,'o-',markersize=5, zorder=1)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]